# Whats the current CSS status for gmail html templates?

Tags: html, css, templates, gmail

A lot of sources state that css in the `<head>` / `<style>` section of an html email template is not supported in gmail. But it seems to work when I tried it. Is all the advice outdated?

Comment: I think it still is a valid advice, since many standalone email client still aren't supporting it. Concerning gmail: it seems they let it throught, although i don't know if they have mechanisms in place to stop you from manipulating gmail itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to ensure Email CSS will work across clients is to make all styles inline. It may work for Gmail, but if your audience is larger you may be out of luck elsewhere.

Here is a good guide to what is supported:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: That link also have gmail not supporting css in `<head>`, which is not the case, so I think it's a bit outdated...

Comment: Regardless, assuming that Gmail is going to be the only recipient of emails is not realistic. The goal should be to have consistency across platforms.